# Can `jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest#getParameterMap` contain null keys or values (in Tomcat)?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

Can `jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest#getParameterMap` contain null keys or values (in Tomcat)?

The documentation isn't clear about that:

> Returns a java.util.Map of the parameters of this request.
> Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For HTTP
> servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form
> data.
> Returns: an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names
> as keys and parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter
> map are of type String. The values in the parameter map are of type
> String array.

Comment: How could you send a parameter without a name? Without a value there can be `null` elements (but they are probably added as `""`). What is the reasoning for this question?

Comment: `How could you send a parameter without a name?` makes sense.

The reasoning is simply how to handle  the keys and values of this map, and don't run into a NPE.

Comment: I doubt there will ever be a `null` key, as a parameter without a name doesn't make sense (and I doubt Tomat will accept it). For the values, write `null` save code which is always smart to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really two questions:

Can it contain null keys? No. The key is the parameter name. If a parameter has no name it simply does not exist.

Can it contain null values? No. The value is the parameter value. A parameter can appear to be valueless in a query string or in post data, but the map stores this as a String array with the single value "". If you attempt to get a value from the map and it returns null, it indicates the parameter with that key/name does not exist.

Since you mentioned Tomcat, it returns [`ParameterMap`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/ParameterMap.html) (the spec specifies `Map`, which is an interface, so different containers may return different types of maps).

In general, you can assume the map you're getting has the same behavior as the one you're interacting with through [`ServletRequest.getParameterValues`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequest#getParameterValues-java.lang.String-).